# Implement knockout.js localization for json items

Tags: knockout.js, localization, single-page-application

I'm building a single page application to manage the order entry for many thousand items, retrieved through json data.
The structure of the order entry is deeply nested: items, packaging, customer, vendor, city, country, week, month and so on (about ten levels).
I decided to use knockout.js for this web application, and the items below for example, at the lowest level, are implemented with observable arrays:

```
{"Code": "BA", "Description": "Bananas", "UnitPrice": 0.35};
{"Code": "AP", "Description": "Apples",  "UnitPrice": 0.25};
{"Code": "OR", "Description": "Oranges", "UnitPrice": 0.45};
...
```

I'm searching now the right way to localize the description for this trade items, because one of the requirement is to always have displayed the order summary and to have some kind of human-readable statistics for all orders.

I'm aware that there are already some well tested knockout plugins and modules that handles localization, for example for i18n, but i need to localize the user interface and the translations of the items in code as well. So, what i need is to have *all the descriptions always available in local language*.

I decided to use the item code to match the localized item description, consequently the translation files are structured as follows:

```
{BA: 'Bananas', AP: 'Apples', OR: 'Oranges'}
{BA: 'Bananen', AP: 'Äpfel', OR: 'Orangen'}
{BA: 'Banány', AP: 'Jablka', OR: 'Pomeranče'}
```

thereafter the localized descriptions are retrieved in a very simple way:

```
function translateByCode(code) {
    var t = vm.language.translation();
    if (t.hasOwnProperty(code))
        return t[code]
    else
        return '';
}
```

Now, because i'm new to knockout.js, i tested three different methods to implement a solution for that:

> sub-observables, computed observables and extenders

1) Sub-observable: i can translate the observable-underlying-array and then apply changes in one step to all items by calling valueHasMutated(), but the user interface has to be update manually.

2) Computed observable: are easy to implement and works automatically, but should i need thousand of extra observables just for the localization?  Once applied, translations never mutates, during order entry.

3) Extender: maybe the the right and most elegant solution, but i don't know if this has the same overhead as a computed observables, or what are the drawbacks.

Here is a sample for what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/ch9ubdu1/3/

It seems to me, that all this tree solutions have pros and cons, and i'm asking: is there already a clear, well-established pattern for that? 
Or someone can explain why i absolutely should use for example, computed observables instead of others?

**EDIT:**

Here is a more structured example with description *lines* as an array attached to an item, and bound to a knockout.js foreach loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/ch9ubdu1/7/

Descriptions are built quick and dirty with no means, but this example shows how they are integrated in the model to dynamically build the markup.

Comment: Will the translations be coming from the server or will they literally be typed into your js?

Comment: translation files are retrieved from the server with ajax requests,.the first considering window.navigator.language, and the subsequent as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a best unique global approach, so i think the answer is: "use the best of all possibilities that knockout has to offer for this job".

For the localization i'm using use a separate view-model, because this is a cut-and-paste already tested solution, i can reuse this view-model everywhere, there are no special functions or references inside.

```
var LanguageViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.languages = ko.observableArray(languages);
    self.selectedLanguage = ko.observable(languages[2]);
    self.translation = ko.computed(function () {
        return resources[self.selectedLanguage().id];
    });
    self.descriptionByCode = function (code) {
        var translation = self.translation();
        if (translation.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
            var resource = translation[code];
            if (resource.hasOwnProperty('name')) return resource.name
            else return resource;
        } else return '';
    };
    self.descriptionLinesByCode = function (code) {
        var translation = self.translation();
        if (translation.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
            var resource = translation[code];
            if (resource.hasOwnProperty('text')) return resource.text
            else return [resource];
        } else return [];
    };
};
```

As in many other common localization pattern, everything that shall be translated must have a *code*, so the two "*core functions*" descriptionByCode() and descriptionLinesByCode() are a common implementation for that.

So, i ended up by following implementation:

**1) use an extender and, optionally, a custom binding for generic translations:**

```
ko.extenders.translation = function (target, option) {
    target.description = function () {
        var code = target.peek();
        return vm.language.descriptionByCode(code);
    };
    target.descriptionLines = function () {
        var code = target.peek();
        return vm.language.descriptionLinesByCode(code);
    };
    return target;
};
```

Now, i could use a data-bind like this:

```
data-bind="text: observable.description()"
```

...but by using a simple custom binding like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.description = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, valueAccessor().description, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

...i can use a more clean and compact syntax:

```
data-bind="description: observable".
```

...also for complex objects inside observables (thanks to neilculver):

```
data-bind="description: 'subproperty'".
```

> Finally, i understood that i cannot skip using computed observables at
>   all, but
>
> 1. i can limit the number of observable properties, because i can put inside an observable an
>      object or an array of objects as well
> 2. i can
>          keep my view-model clean and small by nesting sub-observable properties and computed observables which are not belonging to the first level
>      of their view-model

As a proof of concept, here are two more examples:

**2) use knockout custom functions, for example for localized summary of selected items:**

```
ko.observableArray.fn.summary = function () {
    return ko.computed(function () {
        var items = this(),
            total = 0,
            descriptions = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            var quantity = ko.unwrap(item.quantity);
            if (quantity > 0) {
                descriptions.push(quantity + ' x ' + item.code.description());
                total += quantity;
            }
        }
        return descriptions;
    }, this);
}
```

i'm allowed to do this, because *i always have a quantity and a code*, and my view-model stays very simple and clean:

```
var OrdersViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.fruits = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
        return new Fruit(item);
    }));
    self.fruits.orderSummary = self.fruits.summary();   
};
```

**3) use sub-observables for others, for example for the knockout options binding**

When the options for an item are also supplied together with my data, then my item view-model will be as follows:

```
var items = 
   [{Code: "BA", Quantity: 1, UnitPrice: 0.35},
    {Code: "AP", Quantity: 1, Types: ["RED", "GREEN", "YELLOW"], UnitPrice: 0.25},
    {Code: "OR", Quantity: 0, UnitPrice: 0.45}];

function Fruit(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.code = ko.observable(data.Code).extend({
        translation:null
    });
    self.code.unitPrice = data.UnitPrice;
    self.code.typeOptions = data.Types;
    self.type = ko.observable('');
    self.type.options = ko.computed(function () {
        var l = vm.language.selectedLanguage();
        var typeOptions = self.code.typeOptions;
        var items = ko.utils.arrayMap(typeOptions, function (item) {
            var description = vm.language.descriptionByCode(item);
            return {code: item, description: description};
       });
       return items;
   });
    self.quantity = ko.observable(data.Quantity);
    self.totalPrice = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.code.unitPrice * self.quantity();
    });
}
```

...and now i can have a markup like this below for a localized select element that is automatically reacting to a language switch:

```
 <select data-bind="options:item.type.options,optionsText:'description',optionsValue:'code',value:item.type"></select>
```

The creation of the localized options array could be also extracted from the view-model and putted in a separate function that returns a ko.computed.

Here is a working fiddle for all described above: https://jsfiddle.net/ch9ubdu1/10/

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go with the first two options you suggested for the following reasons:

1. Having to call `valueHasMutated()` on a regular basis probably isn't a good habit to get into. The whole point of knockout is that it does the hard work in tracking dependencies / updating UI for you.
2. I agree with your comments about this approach. Even if your translations needed to be dynamic, creating a computed observables for each translation will clutter up your view model quickly.

An extender would be one solution. A custom binding would also do the job. Picking between these approaches is probably more about personal preferences but  the custom binding does have one advantage that I can think of.

I noticed your example uses a languages view model to access translations for label text e.g. "order" and "total". With the custom biding translations could be implemented without need for an underlying view model, you just need to put the correct code into the view with the correct binding.

So rather than

```
<span data-bind="text: language.translation().TOT">
```

You could just have

```
<span data-bind="translationFor: 'TOT', language: selectedLanguage"></span>
```

Please see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmtaqu49/3/) for an example that uses custom bindings. The [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) has a good description of custom bindings if you want to find out more.

Comment: Doesn't the custom binding solve only one half of this problem? For example: beside trivially simple cases, when i need to group the order amount for some fruits, or sum-up all the orders weight for a specific city, i would first need to group and sum for item category codes and delivery code. Then, i would say: "now, gimme that translated description and let the text binding simply do his job". This is because i think translations more as an attribute of an entity than as binding for a UI. I fear, with a custom binding i would only satisfy DOM elements. Beside this,any clue about performance?